# MongoDB Migrate all existing indexes to new database

Tags: mongodb, indexing, multi-index, robo3t

I have a MongoDB development cluster where i create indexes over time as a part of development improvements. On Testing/Production MongoDB cluster also, i want to maintain the same indexes.

So how do i get all indexes of existing collections and create the same collection indexes on new database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From mongo shell, switch to database from where you want to collect indexes

**Step 1: Switch to existing DB and Run below script**

`> use my_existing_db`

Below script loops through all the collections and constructs a `run command` for each collection.

```
var database = ‘my_new_db' // SHOULD ALWAYS MATCH DESTINATION DB NAME
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection){    
    var command = {}
    var indexes = []    
    idxs = db.getCollection(collection).getIndexes()        
    if(idxs.length>1){
        idxs.forEach(function(idoc){
            if(idoc.name!='_id_'){
                var ns = database+"."+idoc.ns.substr(idoc.ns.indexOf('.') + 1 )
                idoc.ns = ns
                indexes.push(idoc)
            }
        })        
        command['createIndexes'] = collection
        command['indexes'] = indexes         
        print('db.runCommand(')
        printjson(command)     
        print(')')
    }
})
```

Script outputs runCommand's for each collection

**Step 2: Switch to new db and execute runCommands. Done, Cheers!**

`> use my_new_db`

runCommands will be something like this. You can run all the commands in one shot.

```
db.runCommand(
{
    "createIndexes" : "foo",
    "indexes" : [
        {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                "xy_point" : "2d"
            },
            "name" : "xy_point_2d",
            "ns" : "my_new_db.foo",
            "min" : -99999,
            "max" : 99999
        },
        {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                "last_seen" : 1
            },
            "name" : "last_seen_1",
            "ns" : "my_new_db.foo",
            "expireAfterSeconds" : 86400
        },
        {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                "point" : "2dsphere"
            },
            "name" : "point_2dsphere",
            "ns" : "my_new_db.foo",
            "background" : false,
            "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
        }
    ]
}
)
db.runCommand(
{
    "createIndexes" : "bar",
    "indexes" : [
        {
            "v" : 2,
            "unique" : true,
            "key" : {
                "date" : 1,
                "name" : 1,
                "age" : 1,
                "gender" : 1
            },
            "name" : "date_1_name_1_age_1_gender_1",
            "ns" : "my_new_db.bar"
        }
    ]
}
)
```