# MongoDB to Cosmos DB index db migration

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to migrate the indexes from MongoDB to Cosmos DB in an automatic way? I've read that people has to do it by hand, but isn't possible to use a tool or script to do it? or any resource to read about it. I have like 200 collections to migrate with several indexes, it will take me a lot of time to do it manually

Comment: Sure it is possible. Read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/ for the shell command or documentation for the exact driver for the language of choice.

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46993022/14574199) may helps you. It did some thing like export all creating index command then execute the commands in the new database. But pls note, in cosmosdb mongo api, unique index could only be created when the [collection is empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing#migrate-collections-with-indexes). But [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-pre-migration#indexing) also said migration will support migrate unique index in collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like export all the creating indexes command then execute these commands in the new database like what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46993022/15581227) said.

Looping through all the collections and constructs a run command for each collection. Copy the printed command and execute the commands in the new database.

```
var database = ‘my_new_db' // SHOULD ALWAYS MATCH DESTINATION DB NAME
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection){    
    var command = {}
    var indexes = []    
    idxs = db.getCollection(collection).getIndexes()        
    if(idxs.length>1){
        idxs.forEach(function(idoc){
            if(idoc.name!='_id_'){
                var ns = database+"."+idoc.ns.substr(idoc.ns.indexOf('.') + 1 )
                idoc.ns = ns
                indexes.push(idoc)
            }
        })        
        command['createIndexes'] = collection
        command['indexes'] = indexes         
        print('db.runCommand(')
        printjson(command)     
        print(')')
    }
})
```

What you need to note is the unique index could only be created when the collection is empty. Like [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-pre-migration#indexing) said:

> Azure Database Migration Service automatically migrates MongoDB
> collections with unique indexes. However, the unique indexes must be
> created before the migration. Azure Cosmos DB does not support the
> creation of unique indexes, when there is already data in your
> collections. For more information, see Unique keys in Azure Cosmos DB.